# AJAX get() data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a block of jQuery which uses the `$.get()` method in a `setInterval()`. I don't understand how to get data from the second URL to the jQuery code.

**Jquery:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
setInterval(function() {
$.getJSON("check_time.php", function(update) {
    if (update) {
        $("#slideshow").load("phppage.php");
    }
});
}, 600000);
</script>
```

**PHP - check_time.php**

```
<?php
require_once('connect_pdo.php');
header('Content-type: application/json');
$stmt = $conn->prepare("$sqlst = $conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count
                     FROM ads
                     WHERE lastupdate > NOW() - INTERVAL 10 MINUTE");
$sqlst->execute();
$row = $sqlst->fetch();");
$stmt ->execute();
$row = $stmt ->fetch();
$update = $row['count'] > 0;
$updtstatus =  json_encode($update);
echo "$updtstatus";



?>
```

I am not getting the variable from `check_time.php` to the `update` variable in `function(update)`.

Comment: there is something wrong with the query you're using.

Comment: What is wrong with it?

Comment: *"I am not getting the variable"* can you elaborate? I'm pretty sure that `update` contains your data. What do you get when you log it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Small alter in php page

```
$updtstatus =  json_encode(array('count'=>$update));
echo $updtstatus;
```

Now your JSON is in fact something like this `{"count":"true"}`.
So change your `if` statement slightly.

```
   $.getJSON("check_time.php", function(update) {
        if (update.count===true) {
            $("#slideshow").load("phppage.php");
        } else {
            console.log("No results");
        }
    });
```

This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dK5DL/76/) simulates the above answer

Comment: If I test it (by repalcing $("#slideshow").load("phppage.php"); with alert("test"); it still doesn't work?

Comment: Thanks. My count shows {"count":true} instead of a number

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery functions expects data to be returned in JSON format, so simply do so :) I've also found some flaws within your PHP code. This should do the trick:

```
$.get('check_time.php', function(data) {
    console.log(data); // Console logging is always good

    if (data.status) {
        alert('Load slideshow');
    }
});
```

**check_time.php**

```
<?php
require_once('connect_pdo.php');

$json = []; // The JSON array which will be returned

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM ads WHERE lastupdate > NOW() - INTERVAL 10 MINUTE");
$stmt->execute();

$json['status'] = (bool) $stmt->rowCount(); // Status is either false (0) or true (> 0)

echo json_encode($json);
```

Comment: Yeah I noticed a bit too late. His PHP code wasn't correct tho.